# In what ways can a python program terminate without throwing an exception?

Tags: python

I'm asking this because I have some python code that uses a lock file, and I'm wondering in which situations could the program terminate without throwing an exception (or end in an unhandleable way), and subsequently there would be no handling and the lock file would have to be removed manually. I'd like to do something like this:

```
try:
    % Check if lock file exists; if not, create it, do some processing, etc...
finally:
    % Process ended --or-- possibly exception thrown; clean up lock file
```

For example, ctrl+c can be handled by an exception, a broken-pipe can be handled by an exception, etc...

The only case I can think of where the program could terminate without an exception is if the power to the computer gets shut off. In this case I can just write a script to clean all lock files on boot. Are there any others?

**EDIT:** Meant to say "lock files" instead of "flag files"

Comment: In linux there is a kill signal that can not be caught. Not sure about other platforms though...

Comment: In addition to the linux kill signal, there are possible OS breakdowns: Windows blue screen, Linux kernel panic, ... Not 100% sure, but I guess no code runs in these cases either.

Comment: @mkiever: then there are also hardware breakdowns: no power, burned, smashed with a hammer, etc. )

Comment: Well, there's always exiting normally. That doesn't involve an exception, but it's probably not the kind of situation you're thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

`os._exit` will kill a program immediately, but it's use is pretty well discouraged...

Other scenarios involve a user sending `SIGKILL` (*NIX), or the power shutting down or some sort of OS Kernel panic, or your computer fell out of your second story window ...

---

Note that if you have lock files that you'd like to remove, an equivalent (and probably more idiomatic way) to implement the same level of safety is to use a context manager.  `contextlib` can help with this:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def lock():
    try:
       create_lock()
       yield 'whatever you want'
    finally:
       remove_lock()
```

Usage looks like:

```
with lock() as x:
    assert x == 'whatever you want'
    do_stuff_with_lock_safety()
```

Obviously, this is no safer than your original idea of using a `try/finally` (that's what I'm using too) -- But it is less typing per-use, and if the context manager is the *only* way you expose to create/remove the locks, then user's don't need to remember how to clean up after themselves because the context manager does it for you.

Comment: But say within the `with` block the power to the computer gets shut off (or an os._exit() gets called). Will it clean up the lock file?

Comment: @jucestain -- Nope.  That what I mean by "this is no safer than your original idea".  Ultimately, in that case, there's nothing you can do (in python or any other language that I know of)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.exit(status=0)
```

status - optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit

The **negative aspect** of **os._exit()** is that program is finished without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

Comment: Nope.  `sys.exit` raises the `SystemExit` exception.  The finally should still fire if `sys.exit` is called within.